# How to graph results of Cross Validation using cvTools in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, cross-validation, regression-testing

I have specified a simple multiple regression:

```
regression<-lm(y ~ q1 + spread + home + ff, mraf8)
```

I have specified a simple cross validation:

```
cvFit(regression, data = mraf8, y = mraf8$y, cost = rmspe, K = 7, R = 1, foldType = c("consecutive"))
```

and created a cv class object:

```
cvreg<-cvFit(regression, data = mraf8, y = mraf8$y, cost = rmspe, K = 7, R = 1, foldType = c("consecutive"))
```

Next, I want to graph the results of this cross validation

```
densityplot.cv(cvreg, mraf8, subset = NULL, select = NULL)
bwplot.cv(cvreg, mraf8, subset = NULL, select = NULL) here
```

And, in both cases I get the same error:

```
Error: could not find function "densityplot.cv"
Error: could not find function "bwplot.cv"
```

Somehow, as coded even though the cvTools package is installed, it does not recognize the two above basic graph functions.

Comment: Post the results of `sessionInfo()` as an edit to your question.

Comment: if you remove the `.cv` from the plot calls you get more informative errors ( or use `cvTools:::densityplot.cv` to see errors )  : repeated cv plot so seems sensible to use R > 1 ( also looks like you need to change foldType so that is random, otherwise repeat would be the same??)

Comment: 42.  I'll try that when I am back at work on Monday.  Can you educate me on what that would achieve?

Comment: user20650.  Thanks for your input.  I will follow up on your suggestion when I am back at work.  However, even if I have R = 1, and fold Type = consecutive, I still get 49 different out-of-sample observations.  And, I should get a related rmspe.  Mathematically, this should work.  It is no different than calculating the rmse of the learning sample of the model.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, including doing a repeat CV with R > 1, and also changing the Fold Type from "consecutive" to "random".  But, I still got the exact same set of errors.  I did the {cvTools:::densityplot.cv} that suggested to do R>1.  Otherwise, I am still stuck unable to generate any graphs.